# Debugging cortex m3 using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, embedded, cortex-m

I'm using Eclipse and Keil uVision for coding under microcontroller (LPC1766, Cortex M3).

I managed to mix Eclipse and Keil uVision (via mdk-eclipse-plugin) and now i can debug my project in eclipse. 
My question is: is there a way to see (and modify) peripheral registers while debugging? In "Registers" window i can see only core registers.
I heard it's possible with "Expressions" window somehow, but i don't know what expression to add.

Comment: I can add peripheral register in the Expression window if i know the "inner name" for that register. But that name doesn't match name from CMSIS :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use an eclipse plugin such as http://embsysregview.sourceforge.net/
This one supports some of the Cortex M3 reg maps, or you can define your own.  Alternatively, you can have BSP code that uses structs and pointers to match your reg layout.  Then you use the normal watch window to view your registers as structs.

Comment: Thank you, that didn't work with mdk plugin, but did with yagarto. I still can't see "System control block" or NVIC registers though.